# Metro App Navigation causes Home page to reload when calling GoHome or GoBack

Tags: c#, navigation, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, frame

How do I prevent the home page from reloading, when navigating back to it from a call to `GoHome` or `GoBack`?

Currently, the entire main page reloads/initialises itself. Isn't there a way of caching this page so reloading does not happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set Page.NavigationCacheMode to Required.